# Exposing a BBCode parser action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, markitup

What I'm talking aboit is having a controller like:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateResult(false)]
public String Preview(String value) {
    return BBCode.ToHtml(value);
}
```

So user can reference it by url. Is that normal? Probably this is not a high priority question, but I'm just curious?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally controller actions should return ActionResults. So a more correct version of your code would be:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateResult(false)]
public ActionResult Preview(String value) {
    return Content(BBCode.ToHtml(value));
}
```

Comment: I agree! So shouldn't I worry about it is exposed?

Comment: Why would you worry? It's a controller action taking an arbitrary string argument (presumably containing BBCode) and returning the resulting markup.